# tunneling layer 2 ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, debian, vpn, tunnel

Ok, I'm trying to break my previous question down into parts:

This is my reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH_VPN

```
tunneling ubuntu -> debian

1.
ssh -i green.pem root@$HOST

echo 1 | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
echo "PermitTunnel yes" > /etc/ssh/sshd_config
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
ctrl-d logout

2.
sudo ssh -i green.pem root@$HOST -w 0:0 -o Tunnel=ethernet
** logs in, no errors

ifconfig
there is no tap0 or tun0 interface

ip addr show tun0
Device "tun0" does not exist
```

Should there be an interface at this point?

---

In response to a comment:

```
dmesg on remote server:


[    5.451753] EXT3 FS on xvda1, internal journal
[   16.648023] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[   84.265352] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[   84.265370] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky 
root@domU-12-31-39-09-58-EA:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:31:39:09:58:ea  
          inet addr:10.210.95.24  Bcast:10.210.95.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::1031:39ff:fe09:58ea/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:130 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:140 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17963 (17.5 KiB)  TX bytes:29931 (29.2 KiB)
          Interrupt:247 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

```
dmesg on local client:


[   22.739732] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   24.475348] init: plymouth-stop pre-start process (1569) terminated with status 1
[   31.280027] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
```

for comment:

```
tail f /var/log/syslog 

...

Mar 23 02:23:40 domU-12-31-39-13-01-D4 kernel: [   54.188044] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
Mar 23 02:24:27 domU-12-31-39-13-01-D4 kernel: [  101.646030] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
Mar 23 02:24:27 domU-12-31-39-13-01-D4 kernel: [  101.646046] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky 



root@domU-12-31-39-13-01-D4:~# tail /var/log/faillog  
root@domU-12-31-39-13-01-D4:~# 

tail /var/log/auth.log
Mar 23 02:24:35 domU-12-31-39-13-01-D4 sshd[760]: Accepted publickey for root from XXXXXXX port 59391 ssh2
```

on the client side

```
syslog seems interesting

(i did try multiple times)


Mar 22 22:24:27 red NetworkManager[765]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0)
Mar 22 22:24:27 red NetworkManager[765]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 22 22:24:27 red NetworkManager[765]:  /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Mar 22 22:24:33 red NetworkManager[765]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0)
Mar 22 22:24:35 red NetworkManager[765]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0)
Mar 22 22:24:35 red NetworkManager[765]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 22 22:24:35 red NetworkManager[765]:  /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
Mar 22 22:30:56 red NetworkManager[765]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tap0, iface: tap0)
```

Comment: Check your system logs.

Comment: do you mean dmesg?

Comment: No, I mean the system logs. They're various files in the `/var/log` directory.

Comment: I do not think you are a computer.

Comment: I am not a computer, but that does not mean that I am human either.

Comment: ok added more info, it seems like it is adding it, but I just can't see it somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ifconfig -a` shows the interface.

You need to use `-a` to see interfaces that are down. `ifconfig` alone only shows interfaces that are up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Well my question was "Should there be an interface at this point?"  And it turns out there was one.  I just needed to do "ifconfig -a" instead of "ifconfig" to see it....  If you mean that the ubuntu manuals are not correct, and that I haven't fixed them.  Yes, they aren't.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Yes, this is the answer. You need to use `-a` to see interfaces that are down. `ifconfig` alone only shows interfaces that are up.